# Error: "getSurroundingRegion: The requested resource doesn't exist." when cell is empty

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

When I call get `getSurroundingRegion()` on an empty cell with a non-existing surrounding region I get an error: `getSurroundingRegion: The requested resource doesn't exist.` So this Office Scripts code raises an error when A1 is empty and and all of the other cells in the surrounding region are also empty:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sh = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
    let r = sh.getRange("A1") //A1 is empty
    console.log(r.getSurroundingRegion().getAddress()) //raises an error
}
```

The equivalent VBA code would return the address for range A1:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'A1 is empty
    Debug.Print r.CurrentRegion.Address 'prints A1 to the immediate window
End Sub
```

I can work around this by using error handing. But I was wondering if there was a better alternative.

Comment: It seems like a short coming to me that a call to `getSurroundingRegion()` would produce an exception rather than just returning null.  I personally think that's an oversight on Microsoft's behalf and I reckon if you raised it with them, they'd (eventually) provide you with a fix.  For now, I can't see any other way through other than using a try/catch or something.

Comment: Yes I was surprised by it throwing an exception as well. If it just returned the parent range (like VBA does) or null,  you could write elegant solutions around that. But for now a try-catch solution may be the best option.